# Restrict user access on linux

Tags: linux, restriction

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 machine that I can only access using SSH. On this machine I have two users and I want to limit the access to certain files to one of these users.

Basically I want that user to be able to access only its home directory and nothing more. I know that by removing the rx permissions to other home directories for others is one option but I wanted to know if there is another way, a configuration file where I can tell that my user can only have access to that folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrooted jail is the answer.
Like: https://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny

Comment: Thanks for the information. I managed to restrict access after all.